# Pourquoi écrire « tuerie de masse » et pas « tuerie en masse » ?

Tags: prépositions

Je ne trouve pas une façon d'expliquer pourquoi on utilise la préposition *de* au lieu de *en*  car les deux ont différents usages (sens).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Tuerie **de** masse" et "tuerie**s** **en** masse" n'ont pas le même sens.

"Tuerie**s** **en** masse" signifie en nombre, en foule. Dans ce cas là, **les tueries sont nombreuses**. *"En masse" est un adverbe qui s'associe avec un nom commun pluriel.*

Alors que, "tuerie **de** masse" signifie que **la tuerie a touché beaucoup d'individus**. Si on veut préciser que les tueries de masses sont nombreuses, il faudra rajouter un adjectif. Exemple : *de nombreuses tueries de masse*.

Comment: je pensais que "en" agissait comme une préposition au lieu de former un adverbe, merci pour tout clarifier!!

Comment: Vous pourriez en effet avoir des Tueries de masse en masse...